# Effect cleanup potential issue in React 17 for mutable value inside effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

> In React 17, the effect cleanup function always runs asynchronously — for example, if the component is unmounting, the cleanup runs after the screen has been updated.

In the [changelog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#potential-issues) React team has highlighted a potential issue and solution for this:

Problematic Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  someRef.current.someSetupMethod();
  return () => {
    someRef.current.someCleanupMethod();
  };
});
```

Solution suggested by the React team:

> The problem is that `someRef.current` is mutable, so by the time the cleanup function runs, it may have been set to null. The solution is to capture any mutable values inside the effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const instance = someRef.current;
  instance.someSetupMethod();
  return () => {
    instance.someCleanupMethod();
  };
});
```

While the above solution works in most cases, I have created a custom hook, where this solution is problematic:

```
function useMountEffect(funcForMount, funcForUnmount) {
  const funcRef = useRef();
  funcRef.current = { funcForMount, funcForUnmount };
  useEffect(() => {
    funcRef?.current?.funcForMount?.();
    return () => funcRef?.current?.funcForUnmount?.();
  }, []);
}
```

In the above example, I explicitly don't want to capture the mutable value, otherwise, I'll have to re-run the effect when `funcForUnmount` changes. 
*The reason to create the hook in this way is to have the freedom to call the function only on mount / unmount without worrying about stale closure and dependency array.*

**Update:**
I have found one approach for `useMountEffect`

```
function useMountEffect(funcForMount, funcForUnmount) {
  const isMounted = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted.current) {
      isMounted.current = true;
      funcForMount?.();
    }
    return () => !isMounted.current && funcForUnmount?.();
  });
}
```

**But the major questions here are for '*The problem is that someRef.current is mutable, so by the time the cleanup function runs, it may have been set to null.*':**

- How can the `ref.current` go null between unmount and cleanup call in React 17?
- Who is setting the value null? Is it react which can set `ref.current` to null? Or, is it the user who can change in between?
- If a user can change in between how is this possible? Why was it not an issue prior to React 17?

Comment: I dont understand. A value returned by `useRef()` does not need to be passed as dependency, and an empty dependency array means the effect will only ever run once until it is unmounted. So it seems like there is nothing stopping you from doing `const ref = funcRef.current; ref?.funcForMount(); return () => ref?.funcForUnmount();` What's your concern here?

Comment: @yqlim you are missing one subtle issue here. I am using ref because `funcForUnmount` can change during the component lifecycle, and I want to trigger the latest `funcForUnmount`. 
I have created this codesandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-7dsey?file=/src/index.tsx) to explain the difference between both the approaches

Comment: Why is your code not working? you don't have any dependency in the `useEffect` hook, and you're reassigning the `funcFormUnmount` every time. It should run the latest version when unmounting

Comment: @diedu It is working currently. The problem is `someRef.current is mutable, so by the time the cleanup function runs, it may have been set to null` this statement in changelog, which states this can go null. But how will it go null?

Comment: If you have multiple `useEffect` which return a cleanup function and one sets the ref to null then the ref will be null for all cleanup functions that run subsequently leading to undefined behaviour based on the order they run. Not sure if it can be set to null outside of your code though

Comment: @apokryfos This is the default and expected behavior in React 16 is also, then why is this an issue in React 17?

Comment: Ok I've just read the changelog. The classic case of `useRef` was to keep references to underlying DOM elements. Since the cleanups now run asynchronously they would run after those DOM elements would be removed from the DOM. I don't think your use case would be affected since you control 100% of the objects involved though I can't say that for sure